# Two consecutive marginnotes printed over each other

Tags: marginnote

When using the marginnote package and writing two \marginnote{text} fields directly after each other, the two nodes clash into each other. MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\begin{document}
\marginnote{first}
\marginnote{second test}
\end{document}
```

which results in:
[image: output example]

Can this be fixed, so that the second marginnotes automatically is vertically moved -- that is, without using the optional argument to manually move it?

I'm actually trying to create a custom citation command, based on the alphabetic-style-cite-command. I want the citation to put the label in the text and add a marginnote with some more bibliographic information on the cited object. The above problem occurs, when multiple objects are cited, i.e. in `\cite{label1,label2}`.
This then generates the above marginnotes for each cited object. I think the actual DeclareCiteCommand details are not important here, so I only add the above MWE (I can of course also give more details, if necessary).

Comment: Isn't `\marginpar` good for you? If you don't insist on using `marginnote`, simply change `\marginnote` to `\marginpar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me your MWE gives the result you show as does the test where you replace `\marginnote` by `\marginpar`. However then if there is any text on the line with the two marginal notes they are vertically separated.

Did you try:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
% \setmarginnotes{7pt}{128pt}{5pt}
\begin{document}
Text \marginpar{first} \marginpar{second}
\end{document}
```

which for me gives non-overlapping marginal notes.

The `memoir` class macro `\setmarginnotes{sep}{width}{push}` sets the layout for `\marginpar` notes, where `sep` is the space between the textblock and the note, `width` is the width of the note's text and `push` is the minimal vertical space between notes (the `push` value can be set via the standard LaTeX `\marginparpush` length) see section 2.6 in the `memoir` manual. The `sep` and `width` aspects can be individually set via the LaTeX lengths `\marginparsep` and `\marginparwidth`; these are all basic LaTeX lengths that apply to any standard document class. The values I showed in the commented-out `\setmarginnotes` macro are the default values used by LaTeX.

Basically just use `\marginpar` and if necessary tweak its layout to your needs.

If you have to have two or more `\marginpar` on a line with no other text than perhaps `\setlength{\marginparsep}{\baselineskip}` will meet your needs.

Answer (score 4):

From the [documentation](http://ctan.ijs.si/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/marginnote/marginnote.pdf) of `marginnotes`:

> Note: The margin note will be placed at the current vertical line. This means, if you are using two `\marginnote` commands at the same line, they will be put on the same place. This is not a bug but a feature!

If you want to place more margin notes at the same line, use `\marginpar`.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the `marginnotes` documentation. But apparently `\marginpar` does not solve the problem completly. With this, the second note is only moved for roughly halve a baselineskip and both notes still overlap halve.